# Real and Imaginary Parts

Tags: math-mode, fonts

There are multiple questions on this site about redefining the real and imaginary part operators. Mine is a bit pedantic. I am quite used to the standard symbols embedded into LaTeX. However for my students, I think it would be clearer to have the second letter appear also, i.e., to have literally *Re* and *Im*.

The only problem I have is that I'm very fond of the Fraktur used for the in-build commands, and less so of the ones provided by `\mathfrak`:

[image]

Can I get a *Re* and *Im* in the same font as the `\Re` and `\Im` commands?

Comment: The CM provided R and I are a form of Fraktur (not so attractive, in my personal opinion). The problem in using a more complex form is that it's difficult to write by hand. I've long opted for upright Latin Re and Im.

Answer (score 12):

The font used by the `\mathfrak` command can be changed. An easy way to do that is to use the [`mathalpha`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) package. For example, here's a comparison of the letters "Re" and "Im" in Esstix fraktur with the usual `\Re` and `\Im` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frak=esstix]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \verb|\Re|           & \(\Re\)           \\
    \verb|\mathfrak{Re}| & \(\mathfrak{Re}\) \\
    \verb|\Im|           & \(\Im\)           \\
    \verb|\mathfrak{Im}| & \(\mathfrak{Im}\)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The symbols do not match perfectly, but certainly better than in your original example. In the documentation of the `mathalpha` package, many fonts are listed, maybe you will find another font you prefer. I think the Mathpi fraktur font might give the same symbols than `\Re` and `\Im`, but this font is not free.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Where can I find out more about this Mathpi font?

Comment: @LukeCollins I'm not sure, all I know about it is in the documentation of ``mathalpha``. In this documentation there are examples of all of the fonts that can be used with the package, and in fact, if I think the match would be better with this font it is only from the comparison with these examples.

Comment: I've just looked through the [mathalpha documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf), and if anything, it seems the esstix fraktur is the closest (see page 5/6). Of all the frakturs listed there (I'm not sure if that list is exhaustive), it seems the in-build symbol matches none of them, which is strange.

Comment: @LukeCollins Yes, it also seemed to me that the esstix was the closest of these fonts. I think this list is exhaustive only in the sense that these are all of the fonts that can be used with ``mathalpha``, but I'd be surprised if there was no other way to change the fraktur font and no other fonts than these. However, I must say this is the only option I know about.

Comment: I've read that somehow the letter forms part of the CMSY font, in which symbols like `\forall`, `\exists`, `\wp`, etc. reside. Perhaps these two symbols are not taken from some larger font group, and were simply designed for this purpose? It would be a shame! In that case, I think I'll steal the _e_ from esstix and put it on the end of `\Re`.

Comment: @LukeCollins yes that is exactly the case: Re and Im are in cmsy as specific symbols not as part of a fraktur alphabet

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use also the lite version of [`mtpro2`](https://pctex.com/files/managed/1/1b/mtpro2Abbrev.pdf).

[image]

With this example where I have used `newtxtext` package that it gived a clone of Times New Roman; the option `eufrak` for the style *fraktur*, and `zswash` as an alternative shape of `z` in math mode:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite,eufrak,zswash]{mtpro2}
\renewcommand{\Re}{\mathfrak{R}}
\renewcommand{\Im}{\mathfrak{I}}
\begin{document}
\verb|\mathfrak{R}(z)|, output --> $\mathfrak{R}(z)$
\verb|\Re(z)|, output --> $\Re(z)$
\verb|\Im(z)|, output --> $\Im(z)$
\end{document}
```

For my humble opinion I will use the classic notation `Re` and `Im` in the usual mode as the example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\RE}{\mathrm{Re}}
\newcommand{\IM}{\mathrm{Im}}
\begin{document}
$z=a+ib$ where $a=\RE(z)$ and $b=\IM(z)$
\end{document}
```

[image]